# How to apply command to multiple variables in one go

Tags: stata

I have a data set in Stata with 10 variables V1-V10 that looks like this:

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 350cal | Red | Fruit |
| Apple |  |  |  |
| Apple |  |  |  |
| Apple |  |  |  |
| Apple |  |  |  |
| Apple |  |  |  |
| Apple |  |  |  |
| Banana | 550cal | Yellow | Fruit |
| Banana | 550cal | Yellow | Fruit |
| Banana | 550cal | Yellow | Fruit |
| Banana | 550cal | Yellow | Fruit |
| Banana | 550cal | Yellow | Fruit |
| Radish | 90cal | White | Veg |
| Radish |  |  |  |
| Radish |  |  |  |
| Radish |  |  |  |
| Carrot | 60cal | Orange | Veg |
| Carrot |  |  |  |
| Carrot |  |  |  |
| Carrot |  |  |  |
| Orange | 150cal | Orange | Fruit |
| Orange | 150cal | Orange | Fruit |
| Orange | 150cal | Orange | Fruit |
| Tomato | 50cal | Red | Veg |
| Tomato | 50cal | Red | Veg |
| Tomato | 50cal | Red | Veg |
| Tomato | 50cal | Red | Veg |
| Tomato | 50cal | Red | Veg |
| Cherry | 30cal | Red | Fruit |
| Cherry |  |  |  |
| Cherry |  |  |  |
| Cherry |  |  |  |

I have this line of code:

```
replace myvar = myvar[_n-1] if missing(myvar)
```

And I want to apply it to the first 8 variables. I only know how to do this one at a time:

```
replace V1 = V1[_n-1] if missing(V1)
replace V2 = V2[_n-1] if missing(V2)
replace V3 = V3[_n-1] if missing(V3)
```

And so on. But there must be a more efficient way of doing this than repeating this again and again for 8 times.

Comment: See also https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/ as context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way using loops:

```
forvalues num = 1(1)8 {
    replace V`num' = V`num'[_n-1] if missing(V`num')
}
```

I would be cautious with how you are filling the missing data. If you are able, include the by and sort command to make sure you are filling missing information with that associated item or comparable group:

```
forvalues num = 2(1)9 {
    bys V1: replace V`num' = V`num'[_n-1] if missing(V`num')
}
```

Comment: Agree on the importance of `by:` but if that is needed at all then usually some kind of sequence variable is needed too in the code, so typically `bysort id (time):`.

Comment: `forval j = 2/9` exemplifies more compact style.